# How to turn off notifications at a global level without going into focus mode?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, notifications, monterey

Before upgrading to Monterey, I could just turn notifications off and they'd be off. I'd still get notifications on my phone, which is what I want, but I wouldn't get them on my computer, which is what I want.

After upgrading, it appears I can no longer do this. My only options are to:

1. Turn individual notifications off. This is a manual operation I have to do for every single installed app that allows notifications (100s in my case).
2. Go into focus mode, which also puts my phone into focus mode. I have no idea how to uncouple this.

I just want to be able to silence notifications on my computer, but keep them on my phone. This seems like a simple thing to do, but it appears Apple has eliminated this workflow. Has only been able to achieve this after upgrading to Monterey?

Answer (score 1):

You can un-check the "Share Focus State" option in the "Notifications & Focus" preference panel to prevent your phone from going into focus mode. Note: I also find it helpful to turn on focus between 5am and 4:59am, so it's effectively always turned on:

[image: notifications & focus preferences]

Unfortunately this does not disable *all* notifications, though. Bluetooth connection notifications still get through, and I've noticed a couple others. Finding a more complete fix would be very nice.

Comment: Yeah, I genuinely do not understand why Apple wouldn't include a way to silence all notifications. I've done as you suggested, but many notifications still persist, even those that I've "fixed". For example, every single day I get 3-10 notifications to renter a password for my Google account attached to my iCloud Internet Accounts. Every day I enter my password multiple times per day, but the notifications continue. I will have to look into reverting my OS at this point.